# How to collapse all opened selectors or html elements

Tags: html, sass

I mean not to close just one tag, I've just written.
I mean I have a file with a hundreds of elements or selectors.
And i have scroll through them, since they are opened every time I open file.
Please guys, I dont mean auto-close, I mean how to JUST CLOSE ALL OPENED selectors or tags. I use VS code

Comment: For any modern text editors, there should be auto closing tag plugin / built in support.

Comment: vs code should auto close html tag for you by default, are you using html as your file format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fold all tags: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
<kbd>0</kbd>

Fold nth-level tags: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
<kbd>n</kbd>

Unfold All : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
<kbd>j</kbd>

Comment: I'm sorry, It seems every person got my question wrong, I edited It.

Comment: @ВадимКузьмич Do you mean folding?

Answer (score 0):

OK! In this case, you will see a few arrows in VSCode beside where you have opened the starting taglike this:

[collapse option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpOpE.png)

Kindly click on the same to collapse the element...

or use the shortcuts:

- Ctrl + K + 0 to close all elements.
- Ctrl + K + J to open all the elements just in case.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing you can do is to use an IDE and the best one I would recommend you for HTML is VSCode you can install the same using this link

https://code.visualstudio.com/

After you have done the same kindly install an extension called HTML Auto Close Tag in VSCode.

Comment: I mean how to collapse the tags. The thing is, I often have to close opened tags or selectors in files, and need to close them. But this extension does another thing, doesn't it?